# How can I rename files from a list in bash?

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename

I have a file that contains filenames like this:

```
my_cool_file.xxx
my_cool_file2.xxx
my_cool_file3.xxx
```

I have a folder that has:

```
some_file.xxx
some_file2.xxx
some_file3.xxx
```

I would like to have a bash script to take one line from the filename file and rename one file in the folder.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You really need to do a better job of specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note: This answer isn't that good generally, but it solved the OP's problem.**

Do all files end with _file.xxx or _fileN.xxx?

Basically, is what you want to change just the prefix of the filenames?

Assuming I understand your problem correctly, **and that the file without a number is last in file_list.txt** the following should do the trick

```
COUNTER=0
for FILE in `ls *.xxx | sort`; do
    COUNTER=$(($COUNTER+1))
    echo Moving $FILE to `sed -n ${COUNTER}p file_list.txt`
    #mv "${FILE}" `sed -n ${COUNTER}p file_list.txt`
done
```

Comment in the line with `mv` if you want the actual move to happen.

Comment: yes.  That's correct.  there would be a number at the end of each file that I want to rename.

Comment: So the script won't have to read your list of filenames then? All prefixes are the same in the set of files, and are to be changed into the same? Or not?

Comment: Sorry - the prefixes are the same in the files that are in the folder.  The prefixes that are in the file are not.

Comment: Then how do you know what file to rename? By the number at the end?

Comment: It doesn't really matter.  I just want to get one random file to rename to a name that's in the text file.

Comment: Updated my answer. If it doesn't do exactly what you like, please explain and I will fix it. :)

Comment: In a commented line I think it's better to place file in quotes: "$FILE" - in case it has a whitespace in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Or, less clever, but still another way to do it.

My case:

- SRT filenames are named properly.
- Renaming MP4 filenames to match SRT filename structure.

My commands:

```bash
ls *.srt > SRT.txt
ls *.mp4 > MP4.txt
paste -d ';' SRT.txt MP4.txt > SM.txt

while read -r line; do
  mv "$(echo $line | cut -f 2 -d ';')" \
     "$(echo $line | cut -f 1 -d ';' | sed 's/.srt/.mp4/')"
done < SM.txt

rm {MP4,SRT,SM}.txt
```